# Is there a way to "escape" linux commands?

Tags: linux, ssh, server, scp

I'm making an service that will allow users to post files to my web server which will then copy that file (after a few checks) to the image server. The main way of communicating between my web server and my image server will be scp. However, I also want to maintain user filenames, so it would look like this:

1. User posts their file to web server
2. Web server checks if the file is supported
3. Web server checks if file is under file size limit
4. Web server says OK and tries to send to image server
5. Web server runs ("scp " + filepath + " root@imageServer:~/images")
6. Image server receives the file and is ready to send the file to user on request (the folder is public and will be served by nginx)

the dangerous part here is the scp command. I'm not an expert on security, but is there a way that this command can get hijacked the same way a database can get SQL injection? What if somebody named their file to be malicious. Is there a way to safely join the filename to the script? To safely "escape" the command?

I'm using express (node.js) for the web server. Is there another way to send files from the web server to a simple Ubuntu install without unix commands or writing up a REST api for the image server? Is there is, then I might not need to "escape" at all

Btw, the reason why I'm choosing to have the image server and the web server separate is because I want to scale the application in the future. For example, if there were 10 web servers and no central image server, then it would be impossible to retrieve files if the file isn't on the web server you request from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an external command without a shell (and therefore without issues with shell metacharacters) using [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) (or other methods in `child_process`). (Obviously, you must not specify the `shell` option as anything other than the default `false`.)

That lets you not worry about metacharacters in the filepath, but it seems to me that there are plenty of other issues with letting the user provide a filepath name to be used as such on a live filesystem. Personally, I'd autogenerate safe, short names and keep the correspondence from user name to filesystem name in a database somewhere.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to go about it. I'll take your advice and generate a safe filename on the server and then use that to upload to the image server. This way I don't have to trust sketchy data or risk some sort of injection. Thank you!